# ASP.NET Forms - Ajax POST stopped working. Request.Form.AllKeys collection is empty

Tags: asp.net, post, request.form

Recently, an issue appeared in my Windows 2008 R2 virtual machine that results in an empty `Request.Forms.AllKeys[]` collection. My application posts a number of variables using `jquery AJAX`. This was working fine and then something (not sure what) caused the body of the POST request to get lost somewhere in the ASP.NET pipeline. The end result is that the `Request.Form.AllKeys[]` collection is empty. At the same time, using `Fiddler`, i can clearly see the POST request along with the various posted form variables coming from the browser. Also notable, the QueryString variables make it into the Request object just fine. THe other critical point to know is that this functions correctly in my production environment. This is only in my development environment where i'm encountering the issue.

Some of the vital statistics of my environment......

- WIndows 2008 R2 Enterprise
- Visual Studio 2010 (using CSharp)
- Target Framework .NET 4.0
- Using VS Development Server for testing.

Other interesting facts.....

- Other developers of the same application are not experiencing this issue.
- I've tried re-installing .net 4.0 framework
- I've tried using IIS 7 to test (instead of the built-in dev web server).

I'm out of ideas at the moment...if anyone has run into something similar, please throw out ideas/thoughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What are you posting to ? MVC Controller ? Web API Controller ? WebMethod (webforms) ?

Comment: sorry...using wcf services.

Comment: Double chceck the configuration of the bindings of your WCF Service, there may be a difference between your production and local environments. 
Also, try running it on a full IIS (or at least IIS Express) on your environment instead of Cassini.